# Misleading diagnostic message

Tags: command-line, zsh, macos

I generally use /tmp/tmp for throwaway files, but when I accidentally missed the slash, I got:

```
WGroleau@MBP ~ % find /Users  -name "Cami*x" -print > /tmptmp
zsh: read-only file system: /tmptmp
WGroleau@MBP ~ % cd /tmptmp
cd: no such file or directory: /tmptmp
```

**Is there a rationale for calling a nonexistent file "read-only file system"?  Or should I report it as a bug?**

Comment: I often have to redirect `find` because SIP hides the desired output in a zillion messages—apparently security requires we not be allowed to see what is in `~/Library`

Comment: You told it to create a file named `tmptmp` off the root.  The root is a read-only file system.  I don't see the problem.

Comment: Of course you can see what's in `~/Library`, it's owned by you the user. If you want to look in another user's `Library`, then that's what admin use of `sudo` is for. If you can't use `sudo`, well....

Comment: ANY `find` (or `ls` with some options) on my system since SIP was introduced that includes ~/Library gets a ton of "Operation not permitted" on stderr.  To be useful, I have to redirect either stderr or stdout.

Comment: That's not normal. Nothing in my `~/Library` is inaccessible. I think that it is a coincidence it started when SIP was introduced, and instead you have some weird permission issues instead. Probably worth a backup, fresh reinstall and a selective restore of your Documents / App reinstall, but not `~/Library`. Note this is all now a bit off topic from your OP. You seem to have a history of strange errors, maybe this is the root cause?

Comment: I have tried `chmod -RN ~/Library` and `xattr -rc ~/Library` and get similar responses.  This behavior has not only survived an erase and re-install, I've got the same thing on my admin account and on the account I created for my wife that she has never logged into.  (I tried it with sudo on that).  And when I complained to Apple about it, they said nothing.  Not that it's expected, not that it's unexpected.  But yes, it's off-topic.  I only mentioned ~/Library because that's the reason I have to redirect.  @Marc answered the question—might re-do as an answer?

Comment: @AndyGriffiths The errors are probably due to the TCC (Transparency, Consent, and Control) privacy protections. They'll depend on what access Terminal has been granted in the Security & Privacy preferences.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, you're correct.  I checked Settings, and to my surprise, Terminal did not have access.  I'm quite certain I had turned that on long ago.

Comment: Good find.. one of Bob Ross's happy accidents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

`find /Users  -name "Cami*x" -print > /tmptmp`

redirects its output to a file named `tmptmp` in the root.  On current versions of macOS, the root is, in fact, a read-only file system.

Explicitly:

```
$ pwd
/
$ touch tmptmp
touch: tmptmp: Read-only file system
```

So the message from the shell (the shell handles redirection, not the `find` command) is completely appropriate.  It is obviously not a bug.